# Definition of Avogadro's constant

Tags: mole, units

I've read this excerpt from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avogadro_constant) countless times, but I'm still confused:

> The Avogadro number is the approximate number of nucleons (protons or neutrons) in one gram of ordinary matter.

Shouldn't that be *"in one mole"*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The quote you have used is there just behind the Avogadro constant([$\pu{mol-1}$])/Avogadro number(unitless) definition. Many true statements can be misinterpreted, if quoted or considered out of their context.

---

Notice the approximate. It is not the definition.

- $\pu{1 mol}$ is by definition the amount of matter consisting of exactly $N_\mathrm{A} = \pu{6.02214076E23}$ particles(or generally any formal constituent objects).
- The molar mass of nucleons ( protons or neutrons) is approximately $M_\text{nucleon} \approx \pu{1 g/mol}$.
- Practically all the mass of ordinary matter is due its nucleons.
- Therefore,  $\pu{1 g}$ of ordinary matter contains approximately $N_\mathrm{A}$ nucleons, as it contains approximately $\pu{1 mol}$ of them.

Imagine this:

- I say that the current definition of kilogram is based on the fixed value of the Planck constant.
- I then say $\pu{1 kg}$ is the approximate mass of $\pu{1 L}$ of water.
- Does it mean I say the kilogram is defined as the mass of $\pu{1 L}$ of water? Of course it is not.

Comment: The subject and predicate should be reversed! One gram of matter contains approximately Avogadro's number of nucleons [protons + neutrons] [but not Avogadro's number of electrons unless the substance is protium or possibly the natural mix of H2]

Comment: @jimchmst Electrons were not talked about. :-)

Comment: Were not but they are pertinent.

Comment: @jimchmst Not really in this context.

Comment: maybe not but they are pertinent. What is wrong with getting one to think more about this. Also the Wikipedia statement is confusing to at least one person and seems foolish to me.

Comment: @jimchmst If I say 1 kg is the approximate mass of 1 dm3 of water, it does not meant 1 kg is defined as the mass of 1 dm3 of water.

Comment: The Wikipedia statement, if correctly quoted, gives a false implication about the definition of Avogadro's number and did confuse at least one person. Why defend it.  My parenthetical comment on electrons was to try to get a broader thought of what actually is in one gram of nuclides. As to the density of water no one seems to know what that is anymore.

Comment: @jimchmst It is there just behind the  definition. If he used a broader quote...  If it fooled 1 person, than it is still great. Many correct statements fool multiple persons misinterpreting that. Especially if quoted out of context.